# Recursion using for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

I am currently writing a program in which I have to calculate a number recursively using a for-loop. But unfortunately, I have no idea how to correctly implement this function since my current implementation does not calculate the correct answers.

```
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double k = sc.nextDouble();
        double e = sc.nextDouble();
        double q = sc.nextDouble();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            k = (k + (i * e)) * (1 + q);  //The problem I have is that I don't know how to access the previous element of the for-loop
        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: You say you should recursion, but I don't see any method that could be called recursively. Also, what is your attempt? Your code currently does nothing, it doesn't even compile. Looks more like the exercise-template than your attempt. Also explain which part makes trouble. Read [ask], thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Where is your recursive function?

Comment: My program should scan the 4 values that are specified. Using a for loop it should add the next value that is calculated in the loop to the existing value of k. Basically the formula I am trying to implement looks something like
k = ( _k_ + i * e) * (1 + q). The k that is written in italics is the previous k

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do. What is the expected output for example? Why do you want to convert your for loop to a recursive function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    k = (k + (i * e)) * (1 + q);
}
```

You can indeed use recursion.

Just make a method called `calculateK()` and call it recursively, like so:

```
public static double calculateK(double k, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
        return k;
    }
    else 
    {
        return calculateK((k + (i * e)) * (1 + q), i + 1);
    }
}
```